# Why we use flush parameter with Encoder.GetBytes method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, character-encoding, base-class-library

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.getbytes(VS.71).aspx) explains the Encoder.GetBytes Method and there is a bool parameter called flush explained too . The explanation of flush is :

> true if this encoder can flush its
> state at the end of the conversion;
> otherwise, false. To ensure correct
> termination of a sequence of blocks of
> encoded bytes, the last call to
> GetBytes can specify a value of true
> for flush.

but I didn't understand what flush does , maybe I am drunk or somthing :). can you explain it in more details please.

Comment: it seems that there is a "retagging war" here!

Comment: yes, I joined as much as possible.

Comment: @Henk lool :) .you are welcome any time, just keep fighting until I call the backup :D

Comment: @Henk The site charter actively discourages the invention of useless and/or ambiguous new tags, such as `bcl` (15 posts). :)

Comment: Yeah, I added bcl because i 'ran into' it. But VB and C# are useful for this kind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you receive data over a socket connection. You will receive a long text as several `byte[]` blocks.

It is possible that 1 Unicode character occupies 2+ bytes in a UTF-8 stream and that it is split over 2 byte blocks. Encoding the 2 byte blocks separately (and concatenating the strings) would produce an error.

So you can only specify `flush=true` on the last block. And of course, if you only have 1 block then that is also the last.

Tip: Use a TextReader and let it handle this problem(s) for you.

### Edit

The mirror problem (that was actually asked: GetBytes) is slightly harder to explain.

Using `flush=true` is the same as using [`Encoder.Reset()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.reset.aspx) after `GetBytes(...)`.  It clears the 'state' of the encoder,

> including trailing characters at the end of the previous data block, such as an unmatched high surrogate

The basic idea is the same: when converting from `string` to blocks of bytes, or vice versa, the blocks are **not** independent.

Comment: `GetBytes()` is for going from chars to bytes, not vice versa. :)

Comment: I think this mirroring is exactly what is confusing the OP. Perhaps you would care to answer the actual question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Internally the `Encoder` would be implemented with a buffer - this buffer may need to be flushed (cleared) in order to end the read correctly or prepare the `Encoder` for the next read.

[Here](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=buffer+flush&i=39019,00.asp) is one explanation of buffer flushing.

The exact usage of the `flush` parameter is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zxk59x5.aspx):

> true to clear the internal state of the encoder after the conversion; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 3):

Flushing will **reset the internal state of the encoder instance** used to encode the text into bytes. **Why does it need internal state**, you ask? Well, to quote MSDN:

> The flush parameter is useful for flushing a high-surrogate at the end of a stream 
>   that does not have a low-surrogate. For example, the Encoder created by 
>   UTF8Encoding.GetEncoder uses this parameter to determine whether to write out a 
>   dangling high-surrogate at the end of a character block.

If you're using multiple `GetBytes()`, hence, you would want to flush the internal state at the end to terminate any character sequences that need terminating, but *only* at the end, since terminating sequences might otherwise be introduced in the middle of words.

Note that this may be a purely theoretical problem these days. And, you'd be better off [using higher-level wrappers anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858052/why-we-use-flush-parameter-with-encoder-getbytes-method/3858096#3858096). If you do, being drunk will not be a problem.